# Exec a external shell command that have external read input - ex:cookiecutter

Tags: shell-command

As the examble like [cookicutter](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.2/), it have a `read` input in itself that we must type if we use it in normal terminal.

```
$> #comment: this is normal terminal emulator
$> cookiecutter $HOME/cookiecutter/script
$> enter script name: <we input here>
$> generate template....
```

Now I want to write a function that exec it from emacs ecosystem. I try:

```lisp
(defun cookiecutter-el ()
  (interactive)
  
  (if (not (file-exists-p (concat (getenv "HOME") "/" "cookiecutter/")))
      (dired-create-directory (concat (getenv "HOME") "/" "cookiecutter/")))
  (setq cookiecutter-choose (completing-read "PROMT> "
                                             (split-string-and-unquote
                                              (shell-command-to-string "ls -1 (getenv "HOME") "/cookiecutter/") "\n" ) ))
  (eshell-command (concat "cookiecutter " "/home/larva/cookiecutter/"  cookiecutter-choose)))
```

or `(call-process-shell-command)` or something similar is not work.
Because It only work with a process that have output or those process must be terminated.
In  case of cookiecutter, it requires we to input before it terminated the process.

As I remember, `emacs-gdb multiwindow` require we input from "input/output" window.  I think emacs don't support deal with this case by default.

I can do easy thing like exec cookiecutter from terminal emulator, I just want to find out how things work

Comment: In Emacs, you might be interested in [comint](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ComintMode) (also see [Comint: Writing your own Command Interpreter](https://masteringemacs.org/article/comint-writing-command-interpreter)).